# wkhtmltopdf Unable to load library icui18n on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: laravel, wkhtmltopdf

I'm getting the following error when creating a pdf with wkhtmltopdf
Full Error Text:

```
 System error <pre>Unable to load library icui18n "Cannot load library icui18n: (icui18n: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

I'm using laravel
("nitmedia/wkhtml2pdf")

after installing libicu48_4.8.1.1-12ubuntu2_amd64.deb from deb (ubuntu 14.04 doesn't have this in the repository only libicu52) The error changes to something else

```
Exception: System error <pre>Loading pages (1/6)
Warning: SSL error ignored
Warning: SSL error ignored
Counting pages (2/6)
Resolving links (4/6)
Loading headers and footers (5/6)
Printing pages (6/6)
Done
```

I couldn't find any way to deal with this other than get inside the code and remark that exception. the PDF comes out fine.

Comment: ↑ it's also first google result for the error message

Comment: This is a totally different problem which has to do with the library itself, those who find this here (under laravel/nitmedia/wkhtmltopdf) can go here to follow my thread with the developer https://github.com/NitMedia/wkhtml2pdf/issues/41#issuecomment-69498779